# Recommend a good battery optimizer for Windows 8 laptop

Tags: windows-8, battery

I use a Lenovo G500 laptop that runs on Windows 8. I need a good battery optimizer for it which ensures extended battery life and it shouldn't cause much system load. Can anyone recommend me a good battery optimizer ?

I had seen many battery optimizer apps for android devices. Is there such apps for a laptop ?

Comment: Remarkable that neither Tom nor shop.lenovo.com thinks the battery type is worth mentioning. Only when you go into the ordering path you'll see "6 Cell 48 Watt Hour Lithium-Ion" being mentioned.

Comment: @TomJ May be useful http://batterybarpro.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of most important thing is also to **minimize wear of your battery** which rises with battery age and way *how it is used*. You cannot stop aging of the battery, but you can know that **based on how the battery works, its wear increases faster if you keep it always charged at 100%**.

If you are using the laptop connected to AC all the day, you can switch charger circuits of your laptop to stop charging the battery at level much lower than 100%. Return charging mode to 100% capacity only if you are going to travel and expect extended 'unplugged' periods.

#### How to change battery charging mode:

This is the biggest catch. It depends on manufacturer and even model of your laptop. Every manufacturer builds their own charging circuits which need their own software to control them – this is the reason why I can't tell you name of universal tool – there is none. First search in set of your taskbar tray icons. Then check **Start menu** for items named like **Energy Management** or **Power Manager**. Check the keyboard paying attention to those <kbd>Fn</kbd>+key combinations. Consult online. Or simply skip all that and [RTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_the_manual).

For example, on my Lenovo Yoga, **Energy Management** taskbar tray icon opens this screen (labels (A) and (B) were added by me):
[image]

Option (A) enables charging to 100%.
Option (B) limits charging to 60%. Height of this threshold cannot be changed but its main purpose is met.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it better than any battery optimizer software:

1. Set screen brightness to lowest value.
2. Turn off WiFi if you don't use it.
3. Disconnect any USB device that you are not using.
4. Open any application, use it, do what you want to do then close it, do no minimize.
5. Check your metro ui apps to see if you left them running in background.
6. Avoid gaming.
7. Do full charge - discharge cycles (charge your battery then let the laptop run until it is fully discharged and requests you to connect to mains).
8. Go to task manager and check the startup applications. Many can be disabled without affecting functionality as you can start them whenever you need (for example Adobe Reader Speed Launcher, Yahoo! Messenger Tray, Java Scheduled Update).
9. Use lightweight apps (for example Sumatra PDF instead Adobe Reader, AIMP3 instead Winamp)

Comment: 10. Switch power plan to **Power saver** at times when you do not require immediate response times of your apps. Setting a [power plan directly affects CPU performance](http://bradmcgehee.com/2010/07/26/windows-os-power-saving-feature-directly-affects-cpu-performance/) so you have several options to choose between speed and power consumption of your CPU.